# Pasar datos de un JTable a los campos de otro JFrame

Tags: java, java-swing

¿Cómo puedo hacer para pasar datos de un JTable a otro JFrame?

Por ejemplo: Tengo 3 `JTextField` y 2 `JCombobox` en un `JFrame` los cuales son los que debo llenar desde un `JTable` al presionar en un `JFrame` distinto.

He probado intervenir en el evento **KeyPressed**.

```
private void jTablaLocalidadesKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                             
       if ((evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)) {
            int filaSelecionada = jTablaLocalidades.getSelectedRow();
            if (filaSelecionada == -1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se selecciono ninguna fila");

           }else{
                modelo = (DefaultTableModel)jTablaLocalidades.getModel();
                Localidad loc = (Localidad)modelo.getValueAt(filaSelecionada, 1);
                String L = loc.getNombre();
                Localidad CP = (Localidad)modelo.getValueAt(filaSelecionada, 2);
                int codPostal = CP.getCodpostal();
                Localidad DDN = (Localidad)modelo.getValueAt(filaSelecionada, 3);
                String discNac = DDN.getDDN();
                Localidad Provincia = (Localidad)modelo.getValueAt(filaSelecionada, 4);
                int prov = Provincia.getIdprovincia();
                Localidad Zona = (Localidad)modelo.getValueAt(filaSelecionada, 5);
                int Z = Zona.getIdzona();
                ///////////////

                this.agregarCliente.jtxtLocalidad.setText(L);
                this.agregarCliente.jtxtCP.setText(String.valueOf(codPostal));
                this.agregarCliente.jtxtDDN.setText(discNac);
                this.agregarCliente.jcboProvinvias.setSelectedItem(String.valueOf(prov));
                this.agregarCliente.jcboZona.setSelectedItem(String.valueOf(Z));
            }
        }
    }
```

Me sale el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to Datos.Localidad**

Ese es el error que me sale. Tambien he probado hacer.

```
this.agregarCliente.jcboProvinvias.setSelectedItem(modelo.getValueAt(filaSelecionada, 4));
```

Tampoco me funciona, lo que me hace ese codigo simplemente al apretar enter en mi tabla pasa el siguiente registro y asi sucesivamente si se presiona enter.

Clase `Localidad`:

```
public class Localidad {
    private int idlocalidad;
    private String nombre;
    private int codpostal;
    private String DDN;
    private int idprovincia;
    private int idzona;

    public Localidad() {
    }

    public Localidad(int idlocalidad, String nombre) {
        this.idlocalidad = idlocalidad;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getIdlocalidad() {
        return idlocalidad;
    }

    public void setIdlocalidad(int idlocalidad) {
        this.idlocalidad = idlocalidad;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getCodpostal() {
        return codpostal;
    }

    public void setCodpostal(int codpostal) {
        this.codpostal = codpostal;
    }

    public String getDDN() {
        return DDN;
    }

    public void setDDN(String DDN) {
        this.DDN = DDN;
    }

    public int getIdprovincia() {
        return idprovincia;
    }

    public void setIdprovincia(int idprovincia) {
        this.idprovincia = idprovincia;
    }

    public int getIdzona() {
        return idzona;
    }

    public void setIdzona(int idzona) {
        this.idzona = idzona;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nombre;
    }
}
```

¿Como puedo resolverlo?

Answer (score 1):

Tus celdas todas estan del tipo `String`, por eso no resulta el cast.
Puedes transferir los valores directamente mientras usas `setText()`.

```
private void jTablaLocalidadesKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                             
       if ((evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)) {
            int filaSelecionada = jTablaLocalidades.getSelectedRow();
            if (filaSelecionada == -1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se selecciono ninguna fila");

           }else{
                modelo = (DefaultTableModel)jTablaLocalidades.getModel();
                // DefaultTableModel trata las celdas como String 
                String locName = modelo.getValueAt(filaSelecionada, 1);
                String codPostal = modelo.getValueAt(filaSelecionada, 2);
                String discNac = modelo.getValueAt(filaSelecionada, 3);
                String prov = modelo.getValueAt(filaSelecionada, 4);
                String zona = modelo.getValueAt(filaSelecionada, 5);

                // asi los valores se pueden poner tal cual como String
                this.agregarCliente.jtxtLocalidad.setText(locName);
                this.agregarCliente.jtxtCP.setText(codPostal);
                this.agregarCliente.jtxtDDN.setText(discNac);
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Lo e probado pero no me a solucionado mi problema! Al presionar enter solo se desplaza al siguiente registro.

Comment: E encontrado la respuesta, solo me faltaba hacer visible el JFrame al cual estaba pasando los datos hacer toda la logica de seleccionar la fila y luego hacer visible el formulario ej `agregarCliente.jtxtCP.setText(jTablaLocalidades.getValueAt(filaSelecionada, 2).toString());` luego hacemos visible `agregarCliente.setVisible(true);`